# How can I use prepared statements in JList?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, prepared-statement, jlist

I have question regarding JList and the JListItems. I need to implement a JList that contains 10 items in Swing desktop application and by clicking on every item the content of my ContentPane shold be changed. I was told that I have to use PreparedStatement and change the Parameter but i don`t understand how to achieve that. The content represents List with BLOB files (doc,pdf). Can someona guide where should I define every query and how to implement the valueChanged() int the JList.I really apprieciate if someone can link similar tutorial that includes JList and PreparedStatements or post some example here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what exactly is the problem? The preparedStatement? Adding items? Listening to changes? ..? Best to separate out the different aspects and try to solve them independantly of each other. Oh .. and don't forget to re-read your textbook (or any decent tutorial) before doing so :-)

Comment: By clicking on every list item the content should change and I think I need to send different queries to the database. The problem is I dont know where to define these queries and how to apply the prepared statements.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of whatever you have so far.